# For every column oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I would like to know if someone has found a method in which you can get the average or all columns in a table. I currently have a table with 900 columns, and it would make it very tedious to input a query with

```
SELECT AVG(t.columnA), AVG(t.columnB), etc...
```

Is there perhaps another way to go about this.  Assuming they are all NUMBER types.

Comment: Look up the column names in `all_tab_cols` and construct the query logic as a query or using a spreadsheet.

Comment: 900 columns!!! Create a view that does a UNION ALL for each column. (Great to have.) Then do a group by.

Comment: If you can generate a select statement, just find and replace all `,` with `), AVG(`. Then you need to add first `AVG(` and the `)` before `from` keyword. My suggestion is to use Notepad++ if your querying tool does not support find/replace all functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution, based on Gordon's idea:

```
select 'SELECT AVG(' ||all_columns||') FROM YourTable' from (
    SELECT LISTAGG(column_name,',') within group (order by column_name) as all_Columns 
    FROM all_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = 'YourTable')
```

Replace YourTable with your table name, this will generate an output which you will have to copy and run.

It generates all the columns names with comma seperated by them, and beeing concentrated into a select query.

Comment: [AVG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions018.htm) doesn't take multiple arguments; with more than one column the generated SQL will get ORA-00909. But this approach would work with `LISTAGG(column_name,'),AVG(')` instead.